# NoMethodError in StaticPagesController#resume

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to allow users to upload their resumes on my website

Here's what I have in controller

```
def resume
    if signed_in?
    @resume = current_user.resumes.build
  end
end
```

Here's the table I created

```
create_table "resumes", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.boolean  "share"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end
```

I'm using this in view (static_pages\resume.html.erb)

```
<% if signed_in? %>
<%= form_for @resume, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @resume %>
    <div class="ItemInput">Add your resume:<br>
  <%= f.file_field :content %>
</div>
<center><%= f.submit "Upload", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Am I on the right track? I'm getting this error:

```
NoMethodError in StaticPagesController#resume

undefined method `resumes' for #<User:0x5562b40>
```

Here's the resume.rb

```
class Resume < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :share, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  validates :content, presence: true
end
```

Comment: Did you add the relation to your user model?

Comment: You're also missing the second <% end %> in the view. Must end the form_for and end the signed_in? if statement

Comment: I added the relation to my user model like this: `has_many :resumes`. Is this sufficient?

Comment: now I'm getting this error: `undefined method resumes_path' for #<#<Class:0x62e48b0>:0x62e8f48>`. What is causing this?

Comment: What will happen you think eventhough you won't get NoMethod error? You should use paperclip or carrierview to upload files.

Comment: I am using carrierview to upload files

Comment: @rts213 There's no routing for `resumes`, we'd need to see your related routes, and know where/how you're calling resumes_path, and if you're passing it an argument, etc.